# Finding connected components of a set of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In the metric space $(C[0,1],d _∞)$, consider the set:

$$U= \{f \in C[0,1]: f(x)≠0,   \forall x \in [0,1]\}.$$

Prove that $U$ is open and find its connected components.

Proving that $U$ is open is easy, but I don't know how to solve the other part of the problem. I don't know how could I prove that a given subset of $U$ is connected or not.

Note: $(C[0,1],d_∞)$ is the metric space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to R$ with $$d_∞(f,g)= \max_{x\in [0, 1]} |f(x)-g(x)|.$$

Comment: Any two continuous functions into $\Bbb R$ with the same domain can be connected by a path (that is, are homotopic). If you want to avoid $0$ at all times, it appears you can show that there are precisely two path-components and these path-components are open (hence lie in different components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This space has two connected components.

Let $P=\{f\in U: f(0)>0\}$, and let $N=\{f\in U: f(0)<0\}$. Clearly by the Intermediate Value Theorem, if $f\in P$ then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, and 
$f\in N$ then $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Note that each of $P$ and $N$ is convex, and hence path-connected. On the other hand each of $P$ and $N$ is clopen (= closed and open) relative to $U$, hence $P$ and $N$ are the two components of $U$.

To verify that say $P$ is convex, pick $f,g\in P$. For each $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and for each $x\in[0,1]$ define $h_\lambda(x)= (1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda g(x)$. Clearly each function $h_\lambda$ is continuous, and $h_\lambda\in P$ since $h_\lambda(x)>0$ for each $x$ (since $h_\lambda(x)$ is between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive).

Comment: The zero function is not in $P$ but it is not in $U$ either, that is why I said _relatively_ closed (or closed _relative_ to $U$). Alternatively (as @Brian commented) note that each of $P$ and $N$ is open, and obviously they are disjoint, so then they do form different components. If $P$ is open, and if $N$ is the complement of $P$ in $U$, then $N$ is relatively closed in the subspace topology of $U$.